# navigator.sendBeacon data send to server

Tags: javascript, json, performance, server

I'm trying to collect data and post it to the server but,

when im trying to post JSON.stringify(array of jsons), in server side I do not get the post.

if im send only the array of jsons im get the post(cant parse it).

```
var blob= new Blob([makeData(performance.getEntriesByType("resource"),getGuid(),getClientIP())], {type : 'application/json'}); 
    navigator.sendBeacon("https://stage.bitsngo.com/rum",blob);
```

I searched a lot to find an answer,
tried using cors...
for example:

```
 var customParser = bodyParser.json({type: function(req) {
    return req.headers['Content-Type'] === '*/*; charset=UTF-8';
  }});

  app.post('/rum', customParser, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.body));
    ramData.addData(JSON.parse(req.body), function (err, res) {});
  });
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

sendBeacon content type is disabled temporarily - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'sendBeacon' on 'Navigator': sendBeacon() with a Blob whose type is not any of the CORS-safelisted values for the Content-Type request header is disabled temporarily. See http://crbug.com/490015 for details.